# Online band pass filter calculator confusion?

Tags: capacitor, filter

I am using [rf-tools.com's bandpass filter calculator](https://rf-tools.com/lc-filter/) online and, for some reason, it is calculating capacitor values that are usually a polarized electrolytic capacitor, for example, 330 μF.

Can I use an electrolytic capacitor, or can I put multiple non-polarized capacitors in parallel to get the value that is needed?

Comment: I've tried that tool and found it to provide wrong answers. I don't know why/when, but it's prudent to check it in spice or to derive the transfer function and evaluate it at a few key frequencies. I found this site more accurate: https://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/

Comment: @P2000 What do you mean it provides wrong answers? is it calculating values that are totally wrong? What have you tested with this filter calculator?

Comment: What value of frequency were you using?

Comment: Wrt its calculations of L&C, you might be ok, as the issue we had was about frequency scaling if t0 group delay was provided instead of f0: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519992/bessel-lc-ladder-filter/520003#520003 As for the capacitor, if you use elcos then yes the polarity must be correct. So only for biased circuits. Otherwise it's a hazard or at least you won't get the capacitance you thought. Remember you can always use multiple caps to get the value you want

Comment: @Andyaka I am calculating frequency values for a project , in which I need a pretty steep drop off slope narrow bandpass filters. I was on that website calculating values for a 20th order bandpass filters. This website calculates capacitor values that are usually electrolytic for some values , if you select standard component values instead of actual value. The values for the filter do change as it also allows you to set tolerance percentage for the components if you select standard components, If the tolerance is set at 10% or 20% , this is when it usually gives some electrolytic cap values.

Comment: Answer the question.

Comment: does impedance matching matter in your case? If not, you can use a different value to get the L/C in the range you like better. Also, you could try cascading lower order filters each with L/C in better ranges. 20th order is high, you should really check the pole locations / transfer function with the acutal values returned.

Comment: @Andyaka Don't exactly understand your question. Do you mean the frequency ranges I need for my bandpass filters?

Comment: Look at the website you linked and ask yourself what I could be talking about. It's as clear as sunlight.

Comment: @P2000 I am sure I probably don't need a 20th order filter for what I need , but I do need narrow filters. I don't think impedance matching is needed in my case , but though I understand input and output impedance can change the component values . Maybe I should be explaining What I need the filters for. I am making a clone of the Voder (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rAyrmm7vv0)  , which is why narrow bandpass filter is needed, to understand the speech coming out. Impendence is confusing due to potentiometers required in the circuit, which I believe will change the input /output impendence?

Comment: I am a bit confused: you wrote "I was on that website calculating values for a 20th order bandpass filters." and then "I am sure I probably don't need a 20th order filter for what I need"? Maybe the youtube you linked would enlighten the reader, but could you perhaps just include your specs (frequencies/bandwidth, impedance, attenuation, Q etc...) in your question, like @Andyaka asked. If you don't know what all that means, then let us know, and we'd have to cover that first.

Comment: @P2000 I know what you mean for most things like I know what Quality factor, or bandwidth is etc , I have made filters before for other things ; mainly for when I built my own speakers and I don't mainly understand the impedance in the circuit due to how it works . Here are the specifications of the filters I need , I need 10 filters in these ranges  0-225 hz , 225-450 hz , 450-700 hz , 700hz-1 khz , 1 khz -1.4 khz , 1.4 khz -2 khz , 2 khz - 2.7 khz , 2.7 khz - 3.8 khz , 3.8 khz - 5.4 khz , 5.4 khz - 7.5 khz . All of these are bandpass except for 0-255 hz which I'm sure is lowpass.

Comment: @P2000 They also need to be narrow and have a high drop off slope. I can explain what the circuit is, think of a vocoder circuit but with the inputs replaced with 10 resistive keys one for each filter.

Comment: @P2000 The only reason why I said about a 20th order at first, is I was talking to a person who also has a clone of this and he told me about how the filter needs to be really narrow and told me to make a filter that its order is as high as possible, but looking on that filter calculator , a filter with an  order of 5 to 10 should work for what I need, as there really isn't there much difference between the filter graph of a 10 vs a 20 order filter and a filter order below 10 looks like it might work too.

Comment: OK that info helps. It seems you know what you are doing. a) Do you you still have a question about the elco? And b), are you able to simulate the filter, with the component values from rf-tools?

Comment: @P2000 , I understand mostly what I need to do , The only thing I don't understand the input/output impedance , and if the 10 potentiometers in the circuit affects that if any.  I also don't know what I should set the impedance to on the rf-tools website.

Comment: The impedance is probably not a factor, if your signals comes from a line-output, and you are feeding into a pre-amp anyway. You can choose anything in the 1K to 10K range, and see what L&C values you get, and then check the price for the L. 10K input and 1K output is a good starting point. These values determine the attenuation due to the line-output and line-input impedance of your circuitry around the filter. If you can include a sketch of your circuit setup in your question, that would help: line output, pots, filters, line input etc..

Comment: @P2000 , this is one of the versions of the basic circuit diagram (https://ibb.co/hB6hnJw), if you look there are potentiometers on the output after the filters on this circuit. There is also a  more complicated version of this circuit , that has 2 separate filters with a variable gain amp with the Potentiometer in between the 2 filters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113264/discussion-between-p2000-and-michael-weaser).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an electrolytic capacitor, but there are gotchas.

1. Electrolytics have to be biased in order to work properly. If a voltage is used that will only be positive, then you can put the positive terminal in that direction and the cap will be biased. If not then you put two electrolytic capacitors in series.
2. Electrolytics have not so great tolerances and parasitics. This means that a designed filter will vary by 5-20%, which is probably not something that is desired. They also have a higher impedance at high frequencies many times higher than ceramics or other caps, which you can think of as a resistor in series. This hurts their abilty to filter high frequencies.

They are bigger and good for filtering high power applications, a ceramic and electrolytic in parallel to get the best of both worlds.

For a low power filter application, because the capacitor is used in combination with a resistor or inductor (think RC for filter pole) use a higher resistor value and a lower valued cap (or inductor). Example: The same time constant can be achieved with a 10kΩ and 100uf as a 100kΩ and 10uF